# A question about the inconsistent result of $\int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{\cos x}\cos(\sin x) \mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, contour-integration

Here is what have tried to solve the following integral (without any contour integration)

$$I = \int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{\cos x}\cos(\sin x) \mathrm{d}x$$

$$I = \int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{\cos x}\mathrm{Re}\{e^{i\sin x}\} \mathrm{d}x = \mathrm{Re}\Bigg\{\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{\cos x + i\sin x} \mathrm{d}x\Bigg\} = \mathrm{Re}\Bigg\{\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{e^{ix}} \mathrm{d}x\Bigg\}$$

Now taking $e^{ix} = u$, one gets $ie^{ix} \mathrm{d}x = \mathrm{d}u$, thereby $\mathrm{d}x = \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{iu}$.

Since $e^{0i} = e^{2\pi i} = 1$, we end up with

$$I = \mathrm{Re}\Bigg\{\frac{1}{i}\int_{1}^{1}\frac{e^{u}}{u} \mathrm{d}u\Bigg\} = 0$$

which is obviously incorrect because of how the integrand of $I$ looks like:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: if you let $u=e^{ix}$, how is the inversed function defined here?

Comment: @MathFail: $u^{-1} = e^{-ix}$?

Comment: The path of integration is the closed unit circle from $1$ to $1$. Think about how $u$ travels as $x$ tavels from $0$ to $2\pi$.

Comment: @Gary: Yes, but how does that resolve the issue of my solution?

Comment: Why would such an integral be $0$? $\int_1^1$ is a rather misleading notation here.

Comment: $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{\cos x}\cos(\sin x+x)dx=0$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When we wrote $\int_a^b f(x) dx$, **by default**, $x$ goes along the real axis, and $x$ **cannot leave** real axis. If we are more rigorous, we should still use a path notation (or called contour), such as $C_1$, where $C_1$ is the straight line along real axis from $x=a$ to $x=b$. Namely,
$$\int_{C_1} f(x) dx$$

and $C_1$ should reflect the actual trace of the integation variable $x$.

For your case, $x$ goes from $0$ to $2\pi$ along the real axis, no problem.

But when you let $u=e^{ix}$, $u$ is **NOT** along real axis anymore, $u$ **leaves the real axis**, goes along the unit circle, from $(1,0)$ and back to $(1,0)$, so you cannot just put the inital point and endpoint, but need to put the actual trace, namely the unit circle $C$

$$\oint_C g(u) du$$

Comment: I accept this answer because it clearly explains the flawed part of my solution.

Comment: thank you, glad it helps :)

Answer (score 4):

From the step you turned into a complex function, you can use Taylor expansion to finish the job

$$\int_0^{2\pi} e^{e^{ix}}dx = \int_0^{2\pi} 1 + e^{ix} + \frac{1}{2}e^{2ix} +\cdots \:dx$$

$$= 2\pi + 0 + 0 + \cdots = 2\pi$$

Comment: Thanks, but it still does not explain what I have done wrong in my solution. Any insights in that regard?

Comment: @User what happens if you try to solve $$\int_{-1}^1 x^2\:dx$$ with the substitution $ u=x^2$ ?

Comment: you still can do this u-sub, but need to discuss the branches, since $x=\pm \sqrt u$, this is not the flaw part of the OP.

Comment: @MathFail I disagree with your statement "this is not the flaw part of the OP". It very clearly and obviously is as, in your own words, OP did not discuss the branches when doing their own u sub.